# Run a file with HIGH priority

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file

I understand how to run a process or program with HIGH priority, but I want to run an actual FILE (which of course is opened with a program) in high priority using command line in a batch file.

For example, if I wanted to open a program (.exe file) in high priority, I would do:

```
start "" /HIGH c:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe
```

I can easily do this in a batch file.
But what if I wanted to open a particular file, like:

```
c:\user\username\desktop\file.msi
```

I've tried:

```
start "" /HIGH c:\user\username\desktop\file.msi
```

but it doesn't open in high priority.  Only when calling a program, and not a specific file that is opened with a program does it run with high priority.

How can I run **file.msi** in high priority from my batch file?

Comment: Open msiexec with high priority and pass the `/i file.msi` parameter to it.

Answer (score 3):

For any file that requires a handler or runtime to run, you run the handler or runtime application as `/high` and then use whichever method is appropriate for that application to call the file you wish it to run.

As EBGreen notes, for msi files you run msiexec with high priority, and then pass the installer argument and path.

```
start /high "msiexec /i installer.msi"
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to work work with other files other than MSI files.  I tried: **start /HIGH c:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe /i c:\user\username\desktop\file.msi** but it still runs on normal priority.  I was able to open a pdf file with high priority though.

Comment: Does the product install without running msiexec with /high priority? As in, do we know the problem is not with the installer?

Comment: It installs fine, except that when I check the task manager, msiexec.exe is running with normal priority.

Comment: Also, you should try enclosing the full command and arguments in quotes. See the update above

Answer (score 0):

regarding the above: something got lost in translation.

try this:  **create shortcut and edit the target**

`%ComSpec% /C Start /High [/Affinity Hex] Program.exe`

if you wanna see your comspec type "set" at an open cmd prompt and look for the environment variable ComSpec.  It should point to the Windows command interpreter's executable in a protected directory.  I added the affinity since I have a multiple socket motherboard and manage the load.  But, the bracketed piece: it's optional.

However make sure the 'start in' value has the directory for the target exe and quotes around it if it has spaces!

source:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-permanently-set-priority-affinity-with/4e83fd39-34a7-49fe-a54a-ee891c38b737

[image: MS posting]